# angular 2 npm package install error with enterprise registry

Tags: angular, npm

We have an enterprise registry for NPM packages which replicates the standard registry "http://registry.npmjs.org/". I am trying to download following packages (present in package.json)

```
"@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.4",
"@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.4",
"@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.4",
"@angular/forms": "0.2.0",
"@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.4",
"@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.4",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.4",
"@angular/router": "3.0.0-beta.1",
"@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.2",
"@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.4"
```

It is unable to find these packages in enterprise library and couldn't get it from standard registry presumably because of "@" sign. 
I couldn't go to the standard registry directly as it is blocked. I have noted that when I browse to *https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/core* it says "ERROR: No README data found!
"
I can download other packages using enterprise registry.

I can successfully got these packages on my personal machine at home. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are behind corporate proxy currently.I will recommend using proxy in your node settings.

In terminal, you run:

```
npm config edit
```

then set your proxy like this:

```
proxy=http://your proxy url/
https_proxy=https://your proxy url/
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, cannot do that because external access is blocked even with proxy.

Comment: @tangokhi sorry to say that, but until & unless you have access only then it is possible.you need to find some other means then.